# How can I solve "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'append'" in IE11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, cross-browser, vuetify.js

My code like this :

```
  setFooter () {
    if (!this.footer) {
      const div = document.createElement('div')
      let html
      html = "<span><div style='float:left; border-radius: 12px;'></div></span>" +
          "<span style='font-size:12px'>Available</span>"
      div.innerHTML = html
      document.querySelector('.v-date-picker-table').append(div)
      this.footer = true
    }
  }
```

I had search in google and I get reference to add variable. In my code I had add variable. You can see `const` and `let`. But why there exist error? In the chrome and firefox browser, it works

Comment: It's `.appendChild()` not `.append()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript DOM is no `append` method.. use `appendChild` instead... it depends to your DOM tree

Answer (score 2):

`ParentNode.append()` method is not supported in ie you can read about it in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append in the section Browser compatibility.

But there is a Polyfill take a look in the same documentation